# Post request works with content sent as query string, but results in 404 error when content is sent as StringContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've set up an Web Api 2 controller on asp .net to handle a simple post request to localhost just for test purposes. When I use "https://localhost:xxxx/api/test?content=teststring" the controller handles the POST request just fine, however when using just "https://localhost:xxxx/api/test" as the uri with teststring as a StringContent object I get a 404 error. Here is the controller code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostTest(string content)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(content + "\nHiAndBye");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm sending the POST request (from a console app) when I get 404 error:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:xxxxx");
StringContent content = new StringContent("teststring");
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("/api/test", content).Result;
```

How do I fix the 404 error?

Comment: you string by default is part of your query string.  so you need to add it as part of your query string on post. Alternatively you can use [FromBody] if you want to read it from the post body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to fix this was to leave the PostTest controller with no parameters, and use this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result to get the body of the request instead, so the controller now looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostTest()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + "\nHiAndBye");
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: This may have resolved the issue for now but its not the best way. Also changing your return type of Action method to IActionResult will let you return the response with status code in more efficient way. you can just say Ok(response) on success scenario. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Aside from using IActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage, is there anything else you think could be improved in the code or was that the only reason you called this "not the best way"?

Answer (score 0):

In case Johnny's answer in the comments wasn't explicit enough, what you need to do is change your method signature to

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostTest([FromBody] string content)
```

It forces the `content` parameter to be read from the request body instead of the URL.  You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: His answer was pretty clear, I just happened to try it out only now. Unfortunately adding a [FromBody] solved the 404 error but content always came as null instead of "teststring". What solved the issue for me was to remove the string content parameter and use this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result instead